# Selenium proxy authentication with Chrome not allowing https requests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to build a python script that runs selenium webdriver, doing proxy authentication (with user and password) and loads a webpage, via https call. I have searched the internet and found the latest method of successfuly setting up the http proxy connection. However, when trying to load a web page via https, and not http as the examples I have seen use (this is what I need), the Chrome driver brings up a "page moved permanently or inaccessible".

Below is the code I use.

- Few more details:

  - The proxy can only be accesses as http via port 80.
  - Trying to load the same page with http does seem to "go through" but, naturally, the page is not fully loaded.
  - the code below is nothing new. There are several references that show this exactly. The only difference is that I need the desired web
    page to be acceesed via https
  - I am actually not in charge of the proxy setup, so if changing things there is the only way to make it work, that's going to be a
    chellange.

Any help would be appriciated. Tnx.

The selenium script code:

```
PROXY_HOST = 'http://www.myproxy.com'  
PROXY_PORT = 80
PROXY_USER = 'user'
PROXY_PASS = 'password'


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
          },
          bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1200,1100')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver'),
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)

driver.get("https://www.msysecurepage.com")
```